# DbSet doesn't contain definition for FirstOrDefault?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I recently migrated an existing project to .net 4.5 and changed out what this project was using for data access (switching to Entity Framework).

For some reason any time I try to access any functions for a DbSet (`Where`, `First`, `FirstOrDefault`, etc) it throws the error:

> Error 53  'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1<MyProject.Data.Customer>' does
>   not contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefault' and no extension method
>   'FirstOrDefault' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

This uses .net 4.5 and I read that these functions are no longer in System.Linq but are now stored in System.Core.  I have added a reference to System.Core to the project but I am still getting the error.  There is a using statement for System.Linq, but not for System.Core.

Can anyone see why I would be getting this error?  Suggestions on how to fix?

**UPDATE:**

This is the line that throws the error:

```
VIModel Db = new VIModel();
Customer = Db.Customers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CustomerId == CustomerId && c.IsPrimary);
```

and my DbContext:

```
public partial class VIModel : DbContext
{
     ........
     public virtual DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
     ........
}
```

Comment: MSDN and my object browser (in a .NET 4.5 project) say the namespace is System.Linq and it resides in System.Core.dll.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The assembly for [`Queryable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable(v=vs.110).aspx) (the thing that adds the `FirstOrDefault` extension method you are using) is in `System.Core`, however it's namespace is `System.Linq`, you can see this on the MSDN page for it

> **Namespace:**   System.Linq
>   **Assembly:**  System.Core (in System.Core.dll)

You need to have in your project a refrence to `System.Core` and in the file you are trying to use it a `using System.Linq;`

If you have both of these things double check that your project or some project you are refrencing did not create it's own `System.Data.Entity.DbSet<T>` class which does not implement `IQueryable<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: I do have the setup you described (reference to `.Core` and `using` `.Linq`) but the error still comes up.  I looked around for other implementations of `DbSet<T>` but there isn't anything.  My DbContext does define a bunch of members like: `public virtual DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }` where Address is a table in my DB, but that's it.  Can you think of anything else that might be worth checking?

Comment: Can you update your question to include the line of code that causes the error to happen.

Comment: Sure - there are actually about 500 errors because it's being thrown anytime I try to use a function that would be defined in `System.Linq`.  I posted one of the lines in my update.

Comment: Another interesting thing I noticed - `Customers` comes up in intellisense, but but when I type a period after that, nothing comes up in intellisense.  Usually you will see the basic functions (`Equals`, `ToString`, etc), but nothing at all with this (and other EF) classes.

Comment: I'm using an instance (and also a weird naming convention).  I get the confusion - I normally don't name variables with a capital letter, this is a naming convention started by someone else that I am continuing to use going forward.

Comment: Threw some of the code from my DbContext into the update as well

Comment: Yea, I rolled back the change. Out of curiosity do the intelisense methods show up if you do `DbSet<Customer> test1 = null; test1.FirstOrDefault()`, also try `IQueryable<Customer> test2 = null; test2.FirstOrDefault()`. If test2 works but test1 does not, hit F12 on the DbSet and see where it takes you.

Comment: Ok - so I went to do what you suggested and it said that `DbSet` was not found which I thought was strange.  I checked and sure enough I didn't have `System.Data.Entities` added to my references.  So I added that and had the same problem.  Then I remembered that I had to install EntityFramework using NuGet for another project, so I did that and.... bingo!  Everything started working!  So if anyone else comes across this - `Install-Package EntityFramework` in your NuGet console fixes it

Comment: NOT SO INTUITIVE!! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem.
I tried the following solution to solve the problem

- Right click on the project.
- Click on "Property Pages".
- Go to the "Build" tab.
- Set to "Target Framework" 4.5.
- Try "Build"

> I hope this is resolved :)

Comment: How would this help? They *are* in .Net 4.5.

Comment: @GertArnold maybe your problem is different than this. I am sorry.

Comment: It's not my problem. This just doesn't answer the question because .net 4.5 isn't the issue.

Answer (score -1):

This question already has an answer but I had a different cause.

I also needed to have a reference to System before First or Default would show up...